# My animation of pseudo elements is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Hello, my menu anomation is not working and cannot figure out why. Its supposed to work like this: when you click on the menu icon, the icon turns from a hamburger to a cross.

**My HTML is this:** **

```
    <body>
     <div class="menu">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <script>$('.menu').click(function(){
      $this = $(this);
      if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.removeClass('active');
      }
      else {
        $this.addClass('active');    
      }

    });</script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**My CSS is this:**

```
.menu {
  position: absolute; 
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 3%;
  left: 95%;
  z-index: 999;
}
.line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 250ms linear;

}
.line:after, .line:before {
  content: ' ';
  height: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.line:before {
  top: -10px;
}
.line:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
.menu.active .line {
    background: transparent;
}
.menu.active .line:before {
    background: red;
    transform: rotate(-405deg);
    top: 0px;
}
.menu.active .line:after {
     background: red; 
    transform: rotate(405deg);
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Ok about what the app should do.  Could you please also elaborate on what you mean with "is not working" ?

Answer (score 0):

As your `.line` classes are positioned absolutely, your `.menu` doesn't have any dimensions, so can't be clicked on. If you give `.menu` dimensions, it can be clicked on.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h0an7ojx/7/

To clarify on support of the animation of pseudo elements. Historically webkit browsers had an issue animating pseudo elements. [According to the research I carried out](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/), this was fixed. However, it seems around a year ago (early 2014), this fix was reversed. The issue also seems to be apparent in blink browsers. As such, for x-browser support, pseudo element animation should really be avoided.

Even where there is support, the pseudo elements in this example can sit outside the flow of the document, and as such, won't always respond to click events.

Comment: the problem with the jsfiddle is that the transform -405 degrees is not working causing this to become 1 line when clicked as appose to a cross?

Comment: @Clarke Bizarre. It was working fine. I only checked firefox. Just checked with a webkit browser snd its doing what you say. I'll take a look when I get a moment.

Comment: Thanks @dewd, It was my laptops fault because it's working perfectly on my desktop

Comment: @Clarke There is an inherent problem in using pseudo elements like you are doing. 1) their animation doesn't seem to work in all browsers: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/ 2) since click events cannot be bound to them, and because they can sit outside the parent element due to their positioning, you'll find a click doesn't always trigger the parents click event.

Answer (score -1):

You using JQuery **before loading** it. So change your load order and things should work

Comment: I put if after my src code, loaded the page and its still not working?